# Alert.Show() null reference as3

Tags: actionscript-3, alert, nullreferenceexception

I simply want to popup an Alertbox in AS3. I am using Flashdevelop and I got the null reference error when I just run this simple code. I THINK that it has something to do with the stage, but I don't know.

```
import mx.controls.Alert;
public class Main extends Sprite
{
  public function Main()
  {
     Alert.show("hello World","title",Alert.YES | Alert.NO);
  }
}
```

I would like to run this alert and depending what the Alert returns I would love to return a true or false. But I would be glad if we can start with the displaying of the alertdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I wrote all my text in the AS files. When I used an MXML file as view, the alert will pop up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Alert is a flex component. Are you sure you are creating a flex application?

Comment: No. I am actually not sure what I am building. I just clicked on an AS3 Project in Flashdevelop. And I am using an SDK which compiles FLEX and AIR. From the documentation I would suggest it is FLEX. what else can I use to create something like a popupform?

Comment: If you are using Flash Develop, when you are creating a new project there is an Flex 3 or 4 project chose either one.